# Why isn't this writing to my file python

Tags: python, file, csv

Trying to format information from multiple files into a single csv file, anything 'spam' is writing fine, but there is no 'ham' in the file, yet the "print ('ham...." is being called and is outputting to console.

My write ham line is being called (after the else) but it's not being written to the file

```
import os

root_dir = '../res'
output_file = '../res/mass.csv'

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
     with open(output_file, 'w') as dest:
         for filename in files:
            if filename != 'Summary.txt':
                with open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'r') as src:
                    if 'spam' in filename:
                        dest.write(('spam\t' + src.readline())
                                    .decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('utf-8'))
                    else:
                        print ('ham\t' + src.readline()).decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('utf-8')
                        dest.write(('ham\t' + src.readline())
                                    .decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('utf-8'))
```

The file output is a bunch of spam with no ham

spam    Subject: claim your winning offer now !

spam    Subject: winning notification

Comment: In the else case you try to read two lines from src. If you want to print and log the same line, you need to read it only once and store that in a variable.

Comment: That does not affect the output it still does not write to file.

Comment: Both your indentation and brackets (print ham line) are broken.

Comment: But the problem is open(output_file, "w"): This does not append the results, it overwrites. So only the results from your last subfolder are in the file. Change "w" to "a" or swap the outer loop and the open line so you don't reopen the file.

Comment: How many lines are in the `src` file?

Comment: YSelf thank you, that solved it. I just wrote to a list and then wrote the list to the file.